# How can I know when Vector3.Rotate.towards finished?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
    {
        if (playOnce == false)
        {
            Vector3 targetDirection = target.position - transform.position;
            float singleStep = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (playOnce)
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("Picking Up");

            playOnce = false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that its playing the animation before the transform rotating to the target,
I want that the transform will rotate toward the target and if needed also will move a bit closer to the target and than to start the animation so it will be as much as possible look natural when the picking animation play because now it looks like the transform(player) is picking up something near the target and directly the target it self. I think it should look like the hand or the player to pickup the object from the middle more or less.

[Picking up example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2jlQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the object to be fully rotated towards it's target before the pickup animation is played. Then you can store the target's information you need in the OnTriggerEnter and do everything in the update loop instead.

```
Transform _target;
OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
     _target = other.transform;
}
```

You'll need to default the playOnce as false and then in the update loop you can check if the _target is null.

```
playOnce = false // Defaulted to false
void Update()
{
    if (playOnce)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("Picking Up");

        playOnce = false;
    }
    if(_target == null) return;
    
    // Use the _target field now instead of target
    Vector3 targetDirection = target.position - transform.position;
    float singleStep = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);

   // 
   playOnce = true; // Only after you have evaluated that the object is now facing towards the target.
    
}
```

Since I don't know much in 3d space, I don't really know a reliable method to know an object's facing direction, but I think it is the transform.Forward. In order to know if an object is facing to something, you can try to cast a RayCast towards it's transform.Forward or get the Dot product of the two object's transform.Forward. (I think this video might help though about the dot product: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxJnvEpwQHc ). However if it is in 2d I will be willing to help!

Comment: Math-wise, 3D and 2D aren't all that different.  How would you compare a current rotation to a desired rotation?